# Pad Tensorflow training data without affecting results

Tags: python, tensorflow, masking

I am very new to tensorflow and neural networks in general.  I am trying to create a supervised deep learning algorithm to predict a path given a start and stop pair of coordinates using tensorflow and python.  The goal is to train the neural network using an existing dataset of paths using the start-stop coordinates as the input to create a path that looks similar.
My training data consists of 80,126 batches of varying numbers of x and y coordinate pairs.  To use this data for training, I pad the batches to the length of the longest path so that I end up with a matrix with shape (80126, 111, 2). I then transpose the inner vectors so that each batch contains a vector of x coordinates and a vector of y coordinates (I couldn't get my model to work correctly with the x,y pairs).  e.g:

```
[[859, 853, 777, 748, 554, 544, 541, 530, 530, 530, 531, 531,   0, 
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
   [228, 228, 263, 284, 381, 387, 399, 438, 460, 464, 471, 471,   0,
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]]
```

However, the problem is that whenever I use this data to train my model, I end up with results that imply that the zero pad is affecting the results. Like this:
[training data vs trained model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h25ym.png) (blue is the original path minus the zero pad, orange is the trained path)
To solve this, I attempted to add a masking layer that masked the zero timestep values:

```
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0,input_shape=(2, 2)))
```

However, this did not resolve the issue.  It is clear that my understanding of the masking layer is flawed.  What am I doing wrong here, and how do I train a model using zero padded data?

Below is my code for my model  
(I am using tensorflow 1.5 and python 2.6.9)

```
import tensorflow
import numpy as np
import pandas

model = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0,input_shape=(2, 2)))
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(127, activation='relu' ))
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(111, activation='linear'))

model.summary()

inputs = np.load('inputs.npy').transpose(0,2,1)
paths = np.load('paths.npy', allow_pickle=True).transpose(0,2,1)

data_set = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs,paths))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

history = model.fit(inputs, paths, epochs=3)

history.history

prediction = model.predict(inputs)
np.save('results',prediction)
```

For reference, my project is similar to: [Generating mouse movement with ANN](https://medium.com/neuronio/generating-mouse-movement-with-ann-6659c53a6fe2)

Comment: I can see padding is causing noise in data with most numbers of zero than the actual data, you need to take the length of the data to pad based on average length or near to average using histogram method or some other method. If you pad based on the largest data, there might be some random data which is different than the majority of data which doesn't represent for your training.